# Count total amount in gridview VB.net dont count if same ID

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I have this code to count the total amount of sales in my program which works. But for example in Transaction 1 I have orders

Transaction 1 vitamins = 450

Transaction 1 feeds= 350

Total Amount = 800

The code below counts the Transaction 1 twice. That's why I get instead of 800 it shows 1600.

How can I set if the same Transaction ID, don't count the other one?

```
Dim total As Double
For i As Integer = 0 To dgvData.Rows.Count - 1

    total = Val(total) + Val(dgvData.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)

Next

lbltotal.Text = total.ToString("P0,000.00")
```

Comment: I don't see what your problem is based on the example shown. In the example, there is nothing that refers to your Transaction 1 in the question.

Comment: Post a picture of your datagridview.

Comment: By any chance does your datagridview contain a row with the total value at the end?